# Finding Elements of Lists in R

Tags: r, list, character

Right now I'm working with a character vector in R, that i use strsplit to separate word by word. I'm wondering if there's a function that I can use to check the whole list, and see if a specific word is in the list, and (if possible) say which elements of the list it is in.

ex.

```
a = c("a","b","c")
b= c("b","d","e")
c = c("a","e","f")
```

If `z=list(a,b,c)`, then `f("a",z)` would optimally yield `[1] 1 3`, and `f("b",z)` would optimally yield `[1] 1 2`

Any assistance would be wonderful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As alexwhan says, `grep` is the function to use. However, *be careful* about using it with a list. It isn't doing what you might think it's doing. For example:

```
grep("c", z)
[1] 1 2 3   # ?

grep(",", z)
[1] 1 2 3   # ???
```

What's happening behind the scenes is that `grep` coerces its 2nd argument to character, using `as.character`. When applied to a list, what `as.character` returns is the character representation of that list *as obtained by deparsing it*. (Modulo an unlist.)

```
as.character(z)
[1] "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")" "c(\"b\", \"d\", \"e\")" "c(\"a\", \"e\", \"f\")"

cat(as.character(z))
c("a", "b", "c") c("b", "d", "e") c("a", "e", "f")
```

This is what `grep` is working on.

If you want to run `grep` on a list, a safer method is to use `lapply`. This returns another list, which you can operate on to extract what you're interested in.

```
res <- lapply(z, function(ch) grep("a", ch))
res
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 1


# which vectors contain a search term
sapply(res, function(x) length(x) > 0)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. I will definitely keep this in mind for my next project, where I will probably be doing something similar, but alexwhan's method suits my purposes well enough, and it's already started running.

Comment: Hong's answer is great. Just adding a bit of functionality for what it's worth. To get just the hits themselves, use this: `unlist(lapply(z, function(ch) grep("a", ch, value = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 16):

Much faster than grep is:

```
sapply(x, function(y) x %in% y)
```

and if you want the index of course just use which():

```
which(sapply(x, function(y) x %in% y))
```

Evidence!

```
x = setNames(replicate(26, list(sample(LETTERS, 10, rep=T))), sapply(LETTERS, list))

head(x)

$A
 [1] "A" "M" "B" "X" "B" "J" "P" "L" "M" "L"

$B
 [1] "H" "G" "F" "R" "B" "E" "D" "I" "L" "R"

$C
 [1] "P" "R" "C" "N" "K" "E" "R" "S" "N" "P"

$D
 [1] "F" "B" "B" "Z" "E" "Y" "J" "R" "H" "P"

$E
 [1] "O" "P" "E" "X" "S" "Q" "S" "A" "H" "B"

$F
 [1] "Y" "P" "T" "T" "P" "N" "K" "P" "G" "P"

system.time(replicate(1000, grep("A", x)))

   user  system elapsed 
   0.11    0.00    0.11 

system.time(replicate(1000, sapply(x, function(y) "A" %in% y)))

   user  system elapsed 
   0.05    0.00    0.05
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, however, it doesn't work for the case of more complex structures.
E.g. I have a list of lists:
x <- list(list(building = list(name = "Lamellhus", description = "Multi-residential building with 22 apartments", atemp = 1800L)), list(building = list(name = "Punkthus", 
    description = "Multi-residential building with 40 apartments", 
    atemp = 4200L)))

Then grep("Punkthus",x) would work as a charm, however, sapply(x, function(y) "Punkthus" %in% y) would give false for both.

Comment: Don't have time to dig into it, but I suppose, that with %in% it looks only on the first list level.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for `grep()`:

```
grep("a", z)
#[1] 1 3

grep("b", z)
#[1] 1 2
```

Comment: Try `is.vector(z)`. My prediction: You will be surprised.

Comment: It doesn't work to find exact match, with `grep("^a$", z)`

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer - it explains why