# Obtaining the first instance of every element in a list using R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list y, and I want to return to position of the first instance of every element of another list x=c('a','b','c') (i.e. the position of the first a, the first b, etc).

Using

```
which(y %in% x)
```

will simply return all instances rather than the first instance. Another approach is to loop over all elements xi in x and use

```
min(which(y == xi))
```

Is there a way to do this without using a for loop over the elements in x? I've found several queries on stackoverflow on how to find the first instance of a single element in a list, but not for multiple elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Elements of Lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358289/finding-elements-of-lists-in-r)

Comment: The linked thread deals with a somewhat different question. I know how to match list elements, I'm asking specifically how to return the first instance of each element of one list in another list being queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `map` function in the `purrr` package to do this:

```
indices <- purrr::map(x, function(i){
  min(which(y == i))
})
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the purrr library, but this does work, thanks.

Comment: it is similar to the apply family of functions but has more consistent syntax than the apply family

Comment: Lightening fast. Thank you!