# R, filtering for an element in a list in a dataframe cell

Tags: r

Let's say I have a very simple data set. I have 2 columns, Parent Name, Children

```
> d = data.frame(Parents = c("Mark", "Adam"))
> d$Children = list(c("Kid1", "Kid2"), c("Kid3", "Kid4"))
> d
  Parents   Children
1    Mark Kid1, Kid2
2    Adam Kid3, Kid4
```

What I want to be able to do is search by Kid and get the parent name (and the index of that parent's name but this part is easy I presume). So "Kid1" would return "Mark". I can't figure how to do this.

I've tried using the following

```
which(d$Children = "Kid3")
```

But it didn't work, presumably because the datatype is actually list.

Is there a way to get around this? Is using a dataframe here a bad idea? Is there an alternate data strcuture I should use here, I think in Python I might have tried to using a dictionary but I'm not sure how to tackle this problem in R.

Comment: See this existing answer for a (partial) solution in base R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358289/finding-elements-of-lists-in-r. So, e.g., `d$Parents[grep("Kid1", d$Children)]` to return `"Mark"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with `sapply` from base R. `sapply(d$Children, ...)` applies the anonymous `function(x) "Kid3" %in% x)` to every element of `d$Children`. This function checks if `"Kid3"` is present in every element and returns one logical output per row. This logical output is then used to get corresponding `Parent`. Fore more examples look at `?sapply`. -

```
d$Parent[sapply(d$Children, function(x) "Kid3" %in% x)]

[1] Adam
Levels: Adam Mark
```

With `dplyr` -

```
d %>% unnest() %>% filter(Children == "Kid3")

  Parents Children
1    Adam     Kid3
```

Comment: Shree this looks like a good start, although when I try it I get an extra line of output:I get [1] Adam 

and then on the next line: Levels: Adam Mark

Comment: @JedBartlet It's just extra info and not an actual output. It's because `Parent` is a factor column. Use `d = data.frame(Parents = c("Mark", "Adam"), stringsAsFactors = F)` to avoid that.

Comment: Got it, I'll try that. Do you mind me asking what is going on here? While it gives me the answer I want I can't make heads or toes of what's going on here. Is "sapply" a function native to R? I'm trying to understand but I'm not sure what's going on here

Comment: @JedBartlet Added some explanation.

Comment: Hey, really appreciate it. So much to learn, not familiar with sapply, but reading about it now. So as a quick point of clarification, is "function(x)" like any other function you would create/define in R? I always thought syntax wise it went something like:

function_name(input){function calcs}?

Comment: @JedBartlet Yes, `function(x)` is like any other function but in this case defined on the fly. It is called an anonymous function. See [Anonymous Functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions)

Comment: Gotcha, thank you very much for that link, very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For filtering an element, use `lapply` with `%in%`

```
as.character(d$Parent)[unlist(lapply(d$Children,  `%in%`, x = 'Kid3'))]
#[1] Adam
```

---

Or with `Map`

```
as.character(d$Parents)[unlist(Map(`%in%`, "Kid3", d$Children))]
#[1] Adam
```

The columns in the input are `factor` class.  So, it can be converted to `character` class while extracting

---

Or another option is `stack` with `subset`

```
subset(stack(setNames(d$Children, d$Parents)), values == "Kid3")$ind
```

---

Or with `dplyr/purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   filter(map_lgl(Children, `%in%`, x = "Kid3")) %>%
   pull(Parents)
#[1] Adam
```

Or

```
deframe(d) %>% 
    keep(~ "Kid3" %in% .x) %>%
    names
#[1] "Adam"
```

Comment: Damn, really appreciate it, I really like your unlist solution, I'm trying out all the solutions posted here to get a better flavor. Wish I could give you both the check, but just went with the first one I tried. I'm trying to understand your first posted solution, it looks like converts the list into individual elements and then checks if "Kid3" is in there? I've never used unlist or lapply so a bit confused, but thank you very very very much for posting this, it's given me more and more to read/learn