# If a variable belongs to a set

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to write the following `if` condition

```
if( (k==1)| (k==4)| (k==8) | (k== 11)| (k==12)){
       ....
} else{
       ....
}
```

in a more compact way, e.g. like in `php` where `in_array` checks if a value exists in an array.

Comment: try `any(k %in% c(1, 4, 8, 11, 12))`

Comment: @jay.sf it works, thank you!

Comment: Look `grep` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358289/finding-elements-of-lists-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `any`.

```
f <- function(k) if (any(k %in% c(1, 4, 8, 11, 12))) 1 else 0
f(1:12)
# [1] 1
f(13:15)
# [1] 0
f(c(1, 4, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14))
# [1] 1
f(c(2, 5, 9, 13, 14))
# [1] 0
f(c(1, 2, 5, 9, 13, 14))
# [1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Further: all() can be used if 'and' logic is desired instead of 'or'.